# How do I use operations such as -, +, *, / on equations in sympy?

Tags: python, sympy

```
from sympy import *
nx, ny, nz = symbols('nx ny nz')
ax, ay, az = symbols('ax ay az')
bx, by, bz = symbols('bx by bz')
e1 = Eq(ax * nx + ay * ny + az * nz, 0)
e2 = Eq(bx * nx + by * ny + bz * nz, 0)
e3 = Eq(nx**2 + ny**2 + nz**2, 1)
pprint(e1)
pprint(e2)
e4 = e1 * bx
pprint(e4)
e5 = e2 * ax
pprint(e5)
e6 = e4 - e5
pprint(e6)
```

Output:

```
ax⋅nx + ay⋅ny + az⋅nz = 0
bx⋅nx + by⋅ny + bz⋅nz = 0
bx⋅(ax⋅nx + ay⋅ny + az⋅nz = 0)
ax⋅(bx⋅nx + by⋅ny + bz⋅nz = 0)
-ax⋅(bx⋅nx + by⋅ny + bz⋅nz = 0) + bx⋅(ax⋅nx + ay⋅ny + az⋅nz = 0)
```

For

```
e4 = e1 * bx
pprint(e4)
```

I would have expected the output to the similar to this equation

```
bx⋅ax⋅nx + bx⋅ay⋅ny + bx⋅az⋅nz = 0
```

Also no operation seems to really work on multiplied equations. For example in `e6.simplify()` I would have expected the output lose the first term.

How do I correctly use operations such as -, +, *, / on equations?

Answer (score 2):

You can manipulate the left- or right-hand side of an equation by invoking the `lhs` ,`rhs` attributes, respectively. For example,

```
e4 = Eq((bx * e1.lhs).expand(), 0)
pprint(e4)
```

> `ax⋅bx⋅nx + ay⋅bx⋅ny + az⋅bx⋅nz = 0`